# Remove \xa0\xa0 from a string in R

Tags: r, string

I've a string that looks like this: `\xa0\xa0MXL;1000GENOMES:phase_3:MXL` and I want to extract the last 3 capital letters, i.e. `MXL`. If I use the `strsplit` function, there's a problem with the `\xa0\xa0` part, and R does not work. Is there a function/package or any efficient way in R to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A user posted (and deleted) the following answer:

> How about `sub(".*:", "", x)` if there is always a : before it

which efficiently does what I want. However, I do not understand completely the `".*:"` part inside the function.

Comment: That was me.  The regex `.*` means "everything", and adding the `:` to it  makes it say "everything up to the last `:`".  So you've removed everything up to and including the final `:` sign

Comment: Thanks for your help @RichardScriven ! It's clear now.